# What's wrong with this Javascript condition?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a Javascript function like this:

```
function validateInput() {
    var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');

    submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]+$/;

    if (filter.test(search_text) && filter.test(size)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

If the input fields search_text and size satisfy the regex it should allow to submit the form. But even if I put the correct value, it doesn't allow me to submit the form. It works if I only use condition like this:

```
if (filter.test(search_text)){
    return true;
}
```

I want both the input fields to be satisfy the regex. What am I missing?

**Edit**
HTML

```
<form action="/search/" id="ui_element" class="sb_wrapper">{% csrf_token %}
    <!-- <p> <span class="sb_down"></span> -->
    <input class="sb_input" type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search by Name ...">
    <input class="sb_search" id="sb_search" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="validateInput()">
    </p>
    <ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display:none;">
        <li class="sb_filter">Filter your search</li>
        <li>
            <select id="selectmode" name="selectmode" class="filter">
                <option value="filter">Filter</option>
                <option value="date">By date</option>
                <option value="size">By size</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li class="bydateinputs" style="display: none">
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="date_picker" style="width:100px;" name="date" class="text_search" />
        </li>
        <li class="bysizeinputs" style="display: none">
            <label>Size:</label>
            <input type="text" id="size" style="width:100px;" name="size" placeholder="eg: 4 MB" class="text_search" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with the html also?

Comment: what is the "correct value" you input?

Comment: most probably its not able get the element `size`.. post the html

Comment: What text are you using in your input field that should work but doesn't?

It seems to me that the accepted values are sequences of characters between " " and "~", and also empty string is not allowed.

Comment: check what is the return value(true/false) for filter.test(size) !!!.... try with block over condition like if ((filter.test(search_text)) && (filter.test(size)))

Comment: For the disable to work, change

`submitButton.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');` 
to

`submitButton.setAttribute('disabled');`

Comment: Can you post HTML code also??

Comment: @Hariharan: That wouldn't make a difference, it's just redundant. But we need to know the value of `size` to know what's going on.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have posted my HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem you may have is that the submit button remains disabled. When you click it you disable it, if afterwards the user edits his input now can't submit because the button is still disabled.

While the button is disabled it will not generate click events, so the code won't run again.

---

The element with id `size` has no value (in fact, it is not even visible, at least not initially because it is inside an element with the style `display: none`), and your regex doesn't allow empty string.

Change your regex from `/^[\x20-\x7E]+$/` to `/^[\x20-\x7E]*$/` so it allows empty string.

BTW: I suspect you plan into making that element visible with some javascript you are not showing us.

Comment: @user2032220 so it was empty string, I don't know how the element with id `size` is meant to get a value (since the user can't see it) but clearly it is not getting one. Maybe you shouldn't have that field? or the code that shows it needs fixing? or maybe it must be filled automatically with javascript? Anyway, that's up to your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML syntax might be missing some closing or opening tags. I tried to correct them

```
<form action="/search/" id="ui_element" class="sb_wrapper">
         {% csrf_token %}
  <p>  <-- missing opening p tag
   <input class="sb_input" type="text" id="search_text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search by Name ...">
    <input class="sb_search" id="sb_search" type="submit" value="Go" onclick="validateInput()" >

  </p>
  <ul class="sb_dropdown" style="display:none;">
    <li class="sb_filter">Filter your search</li>
    <li>
     <select id="selectmode" name="selectmode" class="filter">
      <option value="filter">Filter</option>
      <option value="date">By date</option>
      <option value="size">By size</option>
     </select>
    </li>
    <li class="bydateinputs" style="display: none">
     <label> Date:</label>
     <input type="text" id="date_picker" style="width:100px;" name="date" class="text_search" />
    </li>
    <li class="bysizeinputs"  style="display: none">
      <label> Size:</label>
      <input type="text" id="size" style="width:100px;" name="size" placeholder="eg: 4 MB" class="text_search" />
   </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call it as..

`onclick="return validateInput();"`

Apart from this, Also you don't need to write else clause.. in your JS..

Your JS could be

```
function validateInput() {
    var search_text = document.getElementById('search_text').value;
    var size = document.getElementById('size').value;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('sb_search');


    var filter = /^[\x20-\x7E]+$/;

    if (filter.test(search_text) && filter.test(size)) {
        submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```